# How to parse but not execute it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Migrating kornshell scripts from solaris 10 to RHEL 7.5

`/bin/sh` is used to execute shell scripts in RHEL 7.5

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Jul 16 12:10 /bin/sh -> bash
```

So, we would like to first parse the complete code to verify their syntax  but not execute it,

For example:

```
sleep 20
echo test
cd /a/b/c
connect # instead of ./connect
```

should just parse the code but not execute it

What is the approach to just parse the code? to verify syntax without executing it.

Comment: sourcing the code = executing it. You're looking for a static analysis tool. Check out https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck

Comment: @swalladge shell check is too much of headache... giving syntax error for every line. It actually does not give error for line 4

Comment: Just did a quick search - it seems that most shells have a `-n` flag to parse but not execute the code (exactly what you were asking for). However note that this won't catch the bug on line 4 since that is still correct syntax.

Comment: @swalladge shall I say `./shell_script.sh -n` ?

Comment: No, it would be `sh -n shell_script.sh`. The `-n` flag needs to be passed to the shell executable, rather than the script.

Comment: @swalladge Does `-n` not take care of `command not found` errors? until script  execute...

Comment: Finding the command to run is part of execution. So if you don't execute the command, you don't know whether it would be found. That's the way the shell works.

Comment: It's entirely possible that a given command executable is created by the previous command (eg. by compiling something). So it would be incorrect to reject the script because a command doesn't exist before the script is executed.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but why migrating from ksh to sh ? why not just use ksh on RHEL ? Just curious.